# creating a python server that can take in requests from postman

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a web app. One of the components is a ML algo that is built on Python. For development, I would like the Python file to be on a server so that I can use postman to send requests to it. I have looked at several articles and I am not quite sure how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Reproducible python code

```
 def analyzeCars(data):
   print(data)
```

I would like to be able to pass data into this script using Postman on a server.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Juliette, you have to create a web api take a look [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/11/python-web-api-flask)

Comment: You've used the flask tag, so do you have a question about flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [Django Rest framework Quickstart](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) to get along with your first API creation.

If you would like to use flask then you can follow below tutorials

- [Flask Quick start](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)
- [Flask quick start Tutorial point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_quick_guide.htm)

Check below basic HTTP method from [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/analyzeCars', methods=['POST'])
def CarAnalysis():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        analyzeCars(request.data)
        return {"status":"success"}
```